# What is the functional purpose of a PD type-C port on a desktop board?

Tags: motherboard, port, usb-c, usb-power-delivery

I've had the ASUSTeK Maximus X Hero Wifi for several years now, but only recently realized the on-board type-C port is intended for PD.  Then a few seconds later, I realized how paradoxical that was: why do I need this if I'm already at my computer?  Of course, recent mobile devices have adopted PD charging as well, but that would be about the only scenario where I can think of it as being useful.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The port is meant to allow you to plugin a PD charging capable device.

Comment: @Ramhound And in most cases (that I've seen, anyway) these are usually seen on docks, hubs, Dex stations, notebooks, etc., most of which would be rendered redundant in the presence of a PC, right?

Comment: Having a Power Delivery capable USB port is perfectly normal on a desktop motherboard.  It would be unusual if a modern motherboard didn't have it.  I assume you mean ASUS AsRock Maximus X Hero not AsRock by the way.  AsRock doesn't have a Maximus product line

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for letting me know, I've corrected the OP.  What, for example's sake, do you use yours for?  Just phone charging or anything else?

Comment: To charge my cell phone, every single day at it has more watts than the stupid charger that came with my phone.

Comment: @cybernard Now that you mention this, how do you know what the wattage is coming out the mobo port?  I agree the OEM chargers nowadays are a bad joke, I was planning to purchase a 100W PD charger but maybe I don't need to...

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/DROK-Voltage-Current-Display-Capacity/dp/B07FL5Y821/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=usb+power+meter   This is only one of a hundred different meters that exist on amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After charging my phone with my notebook charger (regulated by a hub), my eyes were opened.  What I was "missing" was the **charge time**; I knew PD charging was faster, but I had no idea *how much* faster it was.  A *full charge* in less than 15 minutes when the same device takes 3+ hours to charge otherwise is too ludicrous to believe had I not experienced it for myself.